# vite v4+ resolve alias at root level not working

Tags: vite

```js
// vite.config.js

import path from 'path'    
resolve: {
    alias: {
        '@': path.resolve(_dirname)
    }
}

// package.json

type: module

// helpers/fileA.js

import fileA from '@/helpers/fileA.js
```

Throws error:

> cannot find package '@/helpers'